# How to transfer data from one gui matlab to edit box of another gui matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have 2 guis in matlab which are named main and sub. I do some calculation on a image by push button in subgui and want to transfer the results (`handles.sh` and `handles.sv`) to edit box of main gui  and these results should be showed in separate lines in edit box. I used `setappdata` and `getappdata` but it doesn't work and it doesn't show any thing or more probably I made a mistake.

edit box callback of main gui

```
function edithistory_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edithistory (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.sh =  getappdata(0,'horizontal');
set(hObject,'String',num2str(handles.sh));
handles.sh =  getappdata(0,'vertical');
set(hObject,'String',num2str(handles.sv));
```

push button callback of subgui

```
Bw    =  im2bw(handles.D);

s     =  regionprops(Bw, handles.D, 'Centroid');
handles.sx  =  round(s.Centroid(1));
handles.sy  =  round(s.Centroid(2));
handles.roi =  handles.roi/2;
i     =  (handles.sx-((handles.roi)-1)):(handles.sx+ handles.roi);
j     =  (handles.sy-((handles.roi)-1)):(handles.sy+ handles.roi);
  ROI   =  (handles.D(i,j));     
      ROI   =  (2^16)-ROI;
      avg   =  sum(ROI(:))/((2*handles.roi).^2);
     profileh1 = (handles.D(handles.sx,:));
  profileh  = (2^16-profileh1);
 profileh(1)=  profileh(2);
FieldSizeh  =  profileh(profileh>=avg*0.5);
FieldSizeh(:)  =avg;
 handles.sh = (size(FieldSizeh,2)*0.25);
 setappdata(0,'horizontal',handles.sh);
profilev1   =  handles.D(:,handles.sy);
  profilev  = (2^16-profilev1);
 profilev(1)=  profilev(2);    
FieldSizev  =  profilev(profilev>=avg*0.5);
FieldSizev(:)=avg;
 handles.sv = (size(FieldSizev,1)*0.25);
 setappdata(0,'vertical',handles.sv);
```

Comment: Do you actually trigger `edithistory_Callback` after hitting the push button in `subgui`?

Comment: No,how can i  do this?